# Where can I get the JTAPI jar?

Tags: java, jtapi

Where can I find a download of the JTAPI implementation? 
I am getting the following error: `JSpeakerPhone.java:6: package javax.telephony does not exist import javax.telephony.*;`

Comment: @89899.3K: optionally use this too, in case not found: http://www.javagalaxy.com/source/View.jsp?slno=0&tbl=1&category=JTAPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find an implementation for whatever telephony solution you are using. JTAPI is just a specification much like JDBC, you need a specific driver for whatever solution you are using. There is a JTAPI implementation for ASTERIX for example.

Here is [the reference implementation spec for JTAPI 1.4](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr043/index.html).

There is also [gjtapi](http://gjtapi.sourceforge.net/) which might be useful for prototyping.

Answer (score 1):

http://***ipadress-of-cucm***/plugins/jtapi.jar

[Source](https://communities.cisco.com/docs/DOC-49818)

Comment: how should i know? whatever you set it to be

Answer (score 0):

Look here.  Even though it says "specification", you'll also find a link for the API itself:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jtapi-136088.html

These might also be of interest:

http://gjtapi.sourceforge.net/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xtapi/

Comment: Thank you. Something very specific to H.323 would be great.

Comment: Google "java H.323" and it points you to an IBM Alphaworks link for their J323 Engine: http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/j323engine.  I have no idea if it's still supported or not...

Comment: Also look here, regarding H.323 support under Java JMF: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/faq-jmf-137005.html#jmf2-steps